# TSQL to identify long Float values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I'm dealing with a legacy system where I need to identify some bad records based on a column with a data type of Float.

Good records have a value of...

```
1
2
1.01
2.01
```

Bad records are anything such as..

```
1.009999999999999
2.003423785643000
3.009999990463260
```

I've tried a number of select statements where I Convert to Decimal and cast to a varchar and use the LEN() function but this don't seem to work as the good records that are 1.01 become 1.0100000000000000

--Edit
I'm a little closer now as I have discovered I can do (Weight * 100) and all of the good records become whole number values such as 101,201,265,301,500, etc...
and bad ones such as 2.00999999046326 become 200.999999046326

Comment: fyi: the 'sqlserver' tag was renamed to 'sql-server'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works on my SQL Server 2005 DB:

```
select len(cast(cast(1.01 as float) as varchar))
```

Result:

*4*

In fact, it even lets me skip the explicit varchar cast if I want to:

```
select len(cast(1.011 as float))
```

Result:

*5*

---

**Update:**  First of all, I still needed the cast to varchar.  Thinking otherwise was wrong.  That said, I had this all working using strings and was about to post how.  Then you I your update on mulitpling by 100 and realized that was the way to go.  So here's my code for testing both ways:

```
declare @test table ( c float)
insert into @test 
    select * from 
        ( select 14.0100002288818 as c union
          select 1.01 union
          select 2.00999999046326 union
          select 14.01
         ) t

select c,
  case when c = cast(cast(c as varchar) as float) AND LEN(cast(c as varchar))<=5 then 1 else 0 end,
  case when c * 100 = floor(c * 100) then 1 else 0 end
from @test
```

Comment: When I add this to my WHERE clause it returns (0 row(s) affected).
AND LEN(CAST(Weight AS FLOAT)) > 5

Comment: Isn't 'weight' already a float?  have you tried just selecting the weigth column, len(weight), and ordering by len(weight)?

Comment: This does not work as a good record can be 14.01 and returns a LEN() of 5 and a bad 14.0100002288818 also returns a LEN() of 5...
SELECT
 ID,
 Weight,
 LEN(Weight)
FROM
 Products WITH(NOLOCK)
ORDER BY
 LEN(Weight)

Comment: That works now...A good friend of mine helped me over google chat and came up with..AND ((WEIGHT * 100) <> CAST(Weight * 100 AS INT)) which also works.

Comment: Here is your version in T-SQL WHERE Clause...
AND Weight * 100 <> floor(Weight * 100)
AND WEIGHT <> CAST(CAST(Weight AS VARCHAR) AS FLOAT) AND LEN(CAST(WEIGHT AS VARCHAR))<=5

Answer (score 1):

something like this, maybe?  (adjust the precision/scale in the where clause, of course)

```
select val from mytable WHERE CONVERT(decimal(5,2), val) <> val
```

Comment: This still returns lots of results that are 1.01, 2.01, 3.01, etc.  It does show more of the bad ones such as 2.00999999046326

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about using CLR integration and using .net to handle the validation 
see this link [Basics of Using a .NET Assembly in MS SQL - User Functions](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/DotnetAssembliesInMSSQL.aspx)

basically you use .net methods as a user defined function to do the validation; .NET is better at working with numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM YourTable
WHERE CAST(YourFloatField AS DECIMAL(15,2)) <> YourFloatField
```

I'm assuming that anything "bad" has more than 2 decimal places given.

Comment: I still get lots of 1.01,2.01,3.01 etc.. when I add the following to my WHERE clause...AND CAST(WEIGHT AS DECIMAL(15,2)) <> WEIGHT

Answer (score 0):

This really will become a pain in the neck because floats are an imprecise datatype and you will get implicit conversions when casting.

it also depends where you run something like the following

```
select convert(float,1.33)
```

in query analyzer the output is 1.3300000000000001
in SSMS the output is 1.33

when you convert to decimal you need to specify scale and precision

so if you do

```
select convert(decimal(10,6),convert(float,1.33))
```

you get this 1.330000 because you specified a scale of 6

you could do something like this where after converting to decimal you drop the trailing 0s

```
select replace(rtrim(replace(convert(varchar(30),
    (convert(decimal(10,6),convert(float,1.33)))),'0',' ')),' ','0')
```

for a value of 3.00999999046326 you need a scale of at least 14

```
select replace(rtrim(replace(convert(varchar(30),
    (convert(decimal(30,14),convert(float,3.00999999046326)))),'0',' ')),' ','0')
```

Comment: Maybe you miss understood my issue.  When I apply this to the select portion of my sql statement all it does it turn a 3.00999999046326 into 3.01 which dosn't really help me.  Maybe I miss understood your answer...

Comment: I agree, I refuse to allow floats and reals in going forward.

Comment: because you need to increase scale and precision


select replace(rtrim(replace(convert(varchar(30),
    (convert(decimal(30,20),convert(float,3.00999999046326)))),'0',' ')),' ','0')

Comment: @devstuff I banned floats last millennium:-)

Answer (score 0):

Run this:

```
DECLARE @d FLOAT;
SET @d = 1.23;
SELECT ABS(CAST(@d AS DECIMAL(10,2)) - CAST(@d AS DECIMAL(15,8)));
SET @d = 1.230000098;
SELECT ABS(CAST(@d AS DECIMAL(10,2)) - CAST(@d AS DECIMAL(15,8)));
```

Use some threshold such as:

```
ABS(CAST(@d AS DECIMAL(10,2)) - CAST(@d AS DECIMAL(15,8)))<0.00001
```